Updated editable-select.pack.js
I am trying to create an editable first item within my select list but the script listed below is throwing a 404. Is there an updated src i should be using?
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.editable-select.pack.js"></script>

Below is the code for my SelectList:
<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.test.model, new SelectList(new[] { "", "FCU", "Bellows" }), new { @id = "models"})</td>

This is the method for changing the edit:
$(function () {
    $('#models').editableSelect({
        bg_iframe: true,
        onSelect: function (list_item) {
            $('#results').html('List item text: ' + list_item.text() + '<br/> \
Input value: ' + this.text.val());
        }
    });
    var select = $('.editable-select:first');
    var instances = select.editableSelectInstances();
    if (instances != null
        && instances != undefined
        && instances.length > 0) instances[0].addOption("Item 1");
});


I was unaware I was asking for the jquery-editable-select CDN.
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-editable-select@2.2.5/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js"></script>

Found it here:
jquery-editable-selelct CDN

It looks like the issue might be with the source URL for the jquery plugin editable-select. A 404 error normally indicates that the file jquery.editable-select.pack.js is not found at the specified location.
First make sure that you have the correct path to the jQuery plugin file and that the file is in that location.
Once you've confirmed the correct URL or resolved the 404 issue, the rest of your code looks fine for adding an editable first item within your select list.
